# What are some easy to understand applications of Banach Contraction Principle?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, self-learning, examples-counterexamples

I know that Banach contraction principle guarantees a unique solution to problems of the form $$f(x) = x$$ But for the life of me I cannot understand why this problem is important at all. I don't remember encountering such a question in calculus or ODE (at least not the most important problems)

Further more all the examples I can find that applies Banach contraction principle some way always involves tough integral equations (plus hardcore optimal control theory) and some proof that guarantees the uniqueness of the solution. To be honest I learned existence and uniqueness for ODE a long time ago and has never once in my life used it ever since.

What are some simple to understand or physical applications of Banach contraction principle?

Comment: it is for example used in proofs of inverse function theorem, or picard-lindelöf theorem. It is very important in calculus and analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Many problems can be reformulated to precisely ask for a fixed point of a function. A very simple example is the following. Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, thought of as a function $A\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$. Solving $Ax=b$ is an extremely important problem (I hope this does not require elaboration). Now, $Ax=b$ holds if, and only if, $Bx=x$ where $Bx=x - Ax + b$. So, here the problem of solving $Ax=b$ is transformed, via defining a new function $B\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, to a fixed point problem. If you can now equip $\mathbb R^n$ with a metric structure (for instance, one of the many norms you can place on $\mathbb R^n$) such that $B$ is a contraction, then you obtain an iterative process guaranteed to converge to the solution of the system no matter which initial point you use to start the process.

Of course, there are precise methods to solve linear equations, but they tend to be computationally hard. The Banach Fixed Point theorem in this case is thus very useful.

Comment: I completely agree with the point of view of this good answer. As you know very well, this point of view is so important in computational mathematics that it has its own terminology: one speaks of [attractive fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Attractive_fixed_points), and the concept is by no means limited to linear equations, but nonlinear equations as well.

Comment: Thank you! You are better at math than Gauss. How do you go about solving the seemingly harder problem $Bx = x - Ax + b$? :(

Comment: @FemaleTank what are you talking about?

Comment: @IttayWeiss $Ax = b$ can be solved simply using $x = A^{-1} b$. What about $Bx = x - Ax + b$, isn't it more difficult to solve for $x$ for the latter case?

Comment: @FemaleTank how do you propose to find $A^{-1}$? As I said, there are theoretical exact methods to solve systems of linear equations, but they are computationally hard. Having a simple iterative method that is guaranteed to converge to a solution is thus very helpful.

Comment: @ittayweiss Okay solving for $A^{-1}$ can be hard but we are now solving for...$x = B^{-1}x - B^{-1}Ax + b$ $=>$ $x = (B^{-1} - B^{-1}A)x + b$...How do you solve this?

Comment: As I said, if you can find a metric for which $B$ is a contraction, then the sequence $B^n(y)$ converges to a solution, no matter what $y$ is. That's how you solve the original system of equations. Instead of computing the inverse, which can be very hard, all you need to do is compute $B$ again and again. With a bit of luck you also have some handle on the rate of convergence, and so you can determine how good a particular approximation to the solution is.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss:  good luck living up to your new reputation!  Of course, we always knew you were (better at math than Gauss, that is!).  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis I suspect you are being sarcastic. Can you clarify on the Gauss business, in case I'm missing something?

Comment: @Ittay Weiss:  forgive me if I seemed sarcastic; I was not trying to be or to mock your abilities in any way; just joking around; hope I gave no offense.  Peace?

Comment: No offence @RobertLewis I'm just still puzzled by OP's comments here.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss:  as far as the Gauss remark, I see it as an honest complement.  It seems the mathematical remarks are clear enough . . .