# How can I use Banach Contraction Principle to solve $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

Can anyone explain to me how Banach Contraction Principle (fixed point theorem) makes it easier to solve $Ax = b$?

Comment: Define $B(x) := x-Ax+b$, so that solving $B(x)=x$ is equivalent to solving $Ax=b$. Now define a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $B$ is a contraction. Now iterate $B$ until you get close enough to a fixed point (given some tolerance).

Comment: Didn't Ittay Weiss [answer your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366966/what-are-some-easy-to-understand-applications-of-banach-contraction-principle/1367000#comment2782353_1367000) half an hour before you asked this one?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Hi could you link me to an example? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you can find some metric on $\mathbb R^n$ such that the function $B$ is a contraction (doing that may be tricky, or impossible, or easy, depending on the original system of equations). Quite often, a particular norm will do the trick. Now, to solve the original system of equation, is equivalent to solving the fixed point problem $Bx=x$. That can be done now with the Banach fixed point theorem. All that is needed is to start with an arbitrary initial value $y$ and simply iterate $B$ on it. If computationally, computing $B$ is easy, while computing $A^{-1}$ is hard, then this iterative method is appealing. Moreover, for large system the precise methods are not only computationally hard, they are also extremely sensitive to rounding errors. Since a large system is surely to be solved on a computer, this may be a serious issue. The iterative method above tends to be very robust with respect to rounding errors. The reason is kind of obvious, after all the initial value $y$ is not important for convergence, so it does not really matter if you compute the iterates of $B$ on $y$, or, due to rounding errors, once in a while (or every step actually) you are simply using a new $y$ to start the process. Often, a bit of analysis will give one a good handle on the rate of convergence and stability of the process. Both very valuable things when solving numerically.

Comment: thanks, i will look for some concrete examples online